# From a list of integers representing the digits of a number to the corresponding number as BigInteger

Tags: c#, arrays, list, integer, biginteger

I have a simple List(Of Integer) containing integers in the range 0,...,9. Each of these integers is a (base 10) digit of a large number I want to store into a BigInteger.

I already tried the following:

1. create a string appending the converted digits into a StringBuilder
2. use the BigInteger.Parse() method to get the BigInteger number

However, this is extremely slow, and I imagine that, for instance, by using arrays of bytes, I could get the result in a more efficient way.

Could you show me how to convert the List(Of Integer) into the corresponding BigInteger, in the most (time) efficient way (storage is of no concern)? [any VS language, .NET 5 example would be great]

Thank you

Comment: Is it ordered smallest digit first or largest?

Comment: `list.Aggregate(new BigInteger(), (big, n) => (big * (BigInteger) 10) + ((BigInteger) n)` should work if it's largest to smallest, otherwise `list.Select((n, i) => (n, i)).Aggregate(new BigInteger(), (big, ni) => big + (BigInteger) (ni.n * (int)Math.Pow(10, ni.i)))`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you. The list contains the single digits of the number in the order we normally use in everyday usage. For instance, a list of 9, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 6, 7, 5 must become the BigInteger: 923516675.

Comment: Yes, I thought about adding up the powers of the digits, but I just supposed that would be about as time-consuming as the built-in string conversion (?). I was actually thinking about some fast manipulation at the byte array level.

Comment: The built in string conversion is probably fast

Comment: Difficult to do bit twiddling, because the digits are in base-10. I suppose you could combine every 8 digits into a single `long` and add that to the `BigInteger`, not sure it's going to save much time unless you have a really really big number (or lots of them). `var big = new BigInteger(); for (var i = 0; i < list.Count - 8; i += 8) { big = big * (BigInteger) 10; big = big + (BigInteger) (list[i] * 10000000 + list[i + 1] * 1000000 + list[i + 2] * 100000 + list[i + 3] * 10000 + list[i + 4] * 1000 + list[i + 5] * 100 + list[i + 6] * 10 + list[i + 7]) }`

Comment: Perhaps a lookup table with the 10 digits somehow already packed in form of bytes. And then "concatenating" the bytes suitably shifted to create the BigInteger. But I am not sure how to correctly perform this. (Yes  I have really big numbers and a lot of them.)